# how to get a function from input and apply it on data in python

Tags: python

It is normal to get arguments, numbers, and strings from input in python. I am wondering if there is a way to get a user-defined function from the input and apply it in my program.

Suppose I have a program

```
a = [12,34,2,3,4,23,16,84,3]
print(a)
b = get_function_from_input()
print(b(a))
```

and if a user inserts something like following in input:

```
def myfun(X):
   return([max(X),min(X),sum(X)])
```

then my program outputs:

```
[84,2,181]
```

Comment: Yes, the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function.  You should be super-careful using it though, there's nothing stopping that user generated function from wiping your computer/doing other bad stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to link to logic already defined:

```
a = [12,34,2,3,4,23,16,84,3]

def myfun(X):
    return([max(X),min(X),sum(X)])

dispatcher = {'max_min_sum': myfun}

b = input('Enter a dispatcher key:\n')

print(dispatcher[b](a))
```

Demo input / output:

```
Enter a dispatcher key:
max_min_sum
[84, 2, 181]
```

Comment: @rahram, Let me know if this helps. I'm not sure if you need the function to be defined via a string input, or whether naming is sufficient. Defining a function via a text string is likely to be messy.

Comment: First I thought about reading a function from the input and then applying it to my variables, now by the comments of Patrick Haugh, I am so scared. Maybe the safest way is to have a dictionary of all useful functions

Comment: @rahram, I would agree, `exec` is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting the input exactly?

If it helps, just want to point out that functions, like numbers and strings, are objects in python, and can be treated as parameters or return values.

```
a = [12,34,2,3,4,23,16,84,3]

def dostuff(func):
    return func(a)

def myfun(X):
    return([max(X),min(X),sum(X)])

print(dostuff(myfun))
```

outputs

```
[84, 2, 181]
```